# Loading properties from a file AND system properties using Spring

Tags: spring, properties

Searched through some other posts but could not find exactly what I needed, but I would guess this is an easy question..

So I have a property file called myprops.properties

```
myprops.localProp1=localProp1
myprops.localProp2=localProp2
myprops.systemProp=${systemPropertyName}
```

Basically, in this property file I want to use the values as is for localProp1 and locapProp2 but for systemProp, I would like to load the system property.  Let's assume that the system property is always set.

My spring config xml looks like this...

```
<bean id="myprops" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <qualifer value="myprops" />
    <property name="singleton" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list><value>classpath:myprops.properties</value></list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I use the qualifier have this bean autowired and use the qualifier string "myprops" to access it in another class.  All the expected values are there except the myprops.systemProp, it still = ${systemPropertyName}.

How would I get this property to be resolved with the actual system property?

I tried the following in my spring config:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="myprops" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
</bean>
```

This didn't seem to help..

Any ideas?  I'm hoping this is an easy one and I am just misunderstanding a common concept in property configuration.

Note: I had to manually type all the code couldn't copy/paste so please excuse typos.

Thanks.